# Make li squares resize with window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a full width and height div with an li overlaying. The li's are a width of 10% and height of 20vh to fit the entire div as a square. However, when resizing this is not fitting correctly for the div.

I have tried using % and vh, but still the resizing issue. I want to follow the design of the following:- https://adictic.com/home

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.squares li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: '0.4'
    });
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: '0'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.squares {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.squares li {
  width: 10%;
  height: 20vh;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: none;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("/images/bg.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <ul class="squares">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: I see rectangles, not squares.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. I've made a Codepen with your code, though: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMMvow

Comment: Hi Zeth, I basically want to follow this hover square system on the following site:- https://adictic.com/home

Comment: Connexo, I would like the rectangle to always be and resize as squares. Depending on screen size

Answer (score 0):

This problem is possibly ambiguous. The solution implemented certainly is. Browsers are resizable so therefore you can't have boxes which are both square and a fixed percentage of the browser width and height. The 20vh shows that you are aiming for 5 rows and the 10% shows you want 10 columns. Since you can't stop your user from resizing the window there are tradeoffs which need to be made. If the most important aspect is to keep a square than the width and height must be the same. This gives you options to use the width, the height or some combination of the two as your unit. A few small changes to the CSS to can make this square using 10vh (10% of the viewport width) for both the width and the height.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.squares li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: '0.4'
    });
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: '0'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
  .body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  width: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
}

.squares {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.squares li {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10vw;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  background: none;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: orange;
}

.squares li:nth-child(10n+0) {
  clear: left;
}
.squares li:nth-child(10n+10) {  
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <ul class="squares">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</main>
```